# Date comparison with DEC and sy-datum

Tags: abap

I'm trying to perform a date comparison to sy-datum, however, it doesn' t work. I always get an empty result:

```
SELECT *
FROM CRMM_TERRITORY_V AS terr
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ln_terr
WHERE sy-datum BETWEEN terr~VALID_FROM AND terr~VALID_TO.
```

The data type is DEC, therefore, no direct comparison seems to be possible.
Any ideas? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since the validity dates are internally stored as DEC, it seems that no direct comparison is possible. My solution was to perform a datetime conversion and then compare in external format, e.g.:

```
CONVERT TIME STAMP terr-VALID_FROM TIME ZONE 'UTC' INTO DATE l_date_from.
```

Answer (score 1):

The table `CRM_TERRITORY_V`does not have a column called `sy-datum`, try this:

```
SELECT *
FROM CRMM_TERRITORY_V AS terr
INTO CORRESPONDING FIELDS OF TABLE ln_terr
WHERE terr~VALID_FROM LE sy-datum
  AND terr~VALID_TO   GE sy-datum.
```

Comment: Thanks for your help, however, the problem is somewhat bigger. Since the validity dates are internally stored as DEC, it seems that no direct comparison is possible. My solution was to perform a datetime conversion and then compare in external format.